# sum of products expansion (DNF)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How to find the sum-of-products expansion (i.e DNF) of the Boolean function F(w,x,y,z) that has the value 1 if and only if w + x + y = z̄

Answer (score 1):

Create a truth table.  For the output column, write a 1 on any row where w or x or y is equal to z'.  You'll notice we have a 0 output only when w, x, and y are all 0's and z' is 1, or when w, x, and y are all 1's and z' is 0.

```
w   x   y   z   z'   output   minterm
0   0   0   0   1     0
0   0   0   1   0     1       w'x'y'z
0   0   1   0   1     1       w'x'yz'
0   0   1   1   0     1       w'x'yz
0   1   0   0   1     1       w'xy'z'
0   1   0   1   0     1       w'xy'z
0   1   1   0   1     1       w'xyz'
0   1   1   1   0     1       w'xyz
1   0   0   0   1     1       wx'y'z'
1   0   0   1   0     1       wx'y'z
1   0   1   0   1     1       wx'yz'
1   0   1   1   0     1       wx'yz
1   1   0   0   1     1       wxy'z'
1   1   0   1   0     1       wxy'z
1   1   1   0   1     1       wxyz'
1   1   1   1   0     0
```

For each row where the output is 1, write the corresponding minterm.  Then "add" the 14 minterms.